# Is there a way to accept argument choices as a single string

Tags: python, argparse

I'd like to process a string of choices for a given argument rather than either specifying the argument multiple times or using spaces.

I have a script that displays video file metadata. Most of the time I only need the list of files, but occasionally I need to see the files' duration, size, bitrate, etc.

Originally I had an argument for each piece of metadata. -l for length or duration, -d for creation date, -m for modified date, -b for bitrate, -r for resolution, -c for audio channels, -s size, -e for everything, etc... I could specify some or all or none and get exactly the info I was after, but the argument list started getting massively unruly and as I added metadata to display and additional features, I started to run out of logical letter assignments and had to start swapping argument names and I wanted a better way.

I looked to streamline the expression of metadata and thought to consolidate some arguments into one and reduce the length of the final command and typing involved.

Specifically, I'm trying to turn this:

```
script.py -d -t -l -s -b -r -f -c -v -a
```

into this:

```
script.py -m dtlsbrfcva
```

Here's my current function:

```
def get_arguments():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=DESCRIPTION)
    parser.add_argument('-m', action='append', nargs='+', choices=['d','t','l','s','b','r','f','c','v','a','e'],help='Display metadata for each file. Choices: (d)ate, (t)ime, (l)ength, (s)ize, (b)itrate, (r)esolution, (f)ramerate, (c)hannels, (v)ideo codec, (a)spect ratio, (e)verything')
    parser.add_argument('files', nargs='*')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if len(args.files) == 0:
        args.files="."

    return args
```

Using choices seemed like the way to go for this, but when I use "append" for the action and "+" for nargs, I either need to re-specify the argument

```
script.py -md -mt -ml -ms -mb -mr -mf -mc -mv -ma
```

which is worse... 
or use spaces

```
script.py -m d t l s b r f c v a
```

which is somewhat better, I guess?

But I do get informative help:

```
 -m {d,t,l,s,b,r,f,c,v,a,e} [{d,t,l,s,b,r,f,c,v,a,e} ...]
                        Display metadata for each file. Choices: 
                        (d)ate, (t)ime, (l)ength, (s)ize, (b)itrate, 
                        (r)esolution, (f)ramerate, (c)hannels, (v)ideo codec, 
                        (a)spect ratio, (e)verything
```

Now to be clear, if I use

```
add_argument('-m', action="store", help='Display metadata for each file. Choices: (d)ate, (t)ime, (l)ength, (s)ize, (b)itrate, (r)esolution, (f)ramerate, (c)hannels, (v)ideo codec, (a)spect ratio, (e)verything')
```

instead, I can get a string that I can split and process myself, but it's less helpful this way...

```
 -m M          Display metadata for each file. Choices: (d)ate, (t)ime,
                (l)ength, (s)ize, (b)itrate, (r)esolution, (f)ramerate,
                (c)hannels, (v)ideo codec, (a)spect ratio, (e)verything
```

I have also looked into subparsers, but from the reading I've done I'd only be extending my problem to a different layer of code and make my help output less helpful. I'm happy to corrected in this regard.

Ideally, I'm hoping to stick with argparse choices for the programmatic benefits including errors for incorrect options and nicely formatted help, but I am open to other methods. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you consider to write a custom function for type=... instead of choices=... ?

Comment: You might not realise your **original** command can also be invoked as `script.py -dtlsbrfcva`?

Comment: I've read in the docs that type can take a function but I don't quite grasp how to utilize that instead of choices. Can you elaborate?

Comment: `-m dtlsbrfcva` works with a simple `-m` optional.  You just have to parse the string value afterwards. You don't have to do everything in `argparse`!

Comment: True, which I did make reference to, and have made work, but at that point I'm unsure how to get the command line error messages should a wrong value be provided and help messages which is half the incentive to use argparse in the first place.

Comment: `parser.error` method lets you issue your own message, while still showing the default `usage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will accept `-m` possibly followed by a single string composed from letters corresponding to choices.

```
import argparse

MCHOICES = 'dtlsbrfcvae'
def msplit(marg):
    mlist = list(marg)
    for ch in mlist:
        if ch not in MCHOICES:
            raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(f"{ch} is not a valid choice")
    return mlist


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="<put description here>")
parser.add_argument('-m', type=msplit, nargs='?', const=[], default=[], help='Display metadata for each file...')

# some examples:
args = parser.parse_args("-m dtlsv".split())
print(args)
args = parser.parse_args("-m".split()) # const=... is used in this case (bare -m)
print(args)
args = parser.parse_args("".split()) # default=... is used in this case (no -m at all)
print(args)
```

UPDATE:

When setting a default, strings are processed as if they were arguments. Non-strings are assigned directly, they are not processed by `mlist`. E.g. to make "-m e" the default metadata choice, use either `default='e'` or `default=['e']` (and `const=...` as well). (thanks to @hpaulj for his comment)

---

This alternative makes the string with choices mandatory:

```
parser.add_argument('-m', type=msplit, default=[], help='Display metadata for each file...')
```

Comment: Ok. I get this. I did find a similar example but didn't quite make the connection to my own scenario. Thank you.

Comment: Two things I cannot figure out from this though: I've tried setting default='e' if -m is provided without any options and it stays empty. Also, how would I go about replacing the string in the help output that would normally be populated by the choices setting. Currently it displays [M] and I'd like to have it show dtlsbrfcvae or even d, t, l, s, b, r, f. c, v, a, e. Thanks again.

Comment: @mg I have updated my anwser with info about setting the defaults. Regarding the help, `argparse` obviously cannot autodetect what an external function does. The only way to have a decent usage instruction is to write an useful `help=...` description. If it would be too long, you may want to include something like "see below" and put details into `epilog=` section.

Comment: A string default is passed through the `type` function at the end - if it was not replaced by user input.  Non-string defaults are left as-is.  Similarly for the `const` parameter.

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you, I was trying to be brief and it ended up with a misleading half-true. Section about defaults updated.

Comment: @VPfB and @hpaulj Thanks for the guidance. I was getting some unexpected behaviour from `default=` but I omitted it and set `const='e'` I was able to get things functioning the way I was hoping. I'm still trying to decide how I want to approach the help info, but the error messages and parsing of string input to a list is working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It’s perfectly acceptable to pass individual options stacked together. Thus:

```
script.py -d -t -l -s -b -r -f -c -v -a
```

can already be equivalently invoked as:

```
script.py -dtlsbrfcva
```

which probably addresses your concerns without any change required.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I did use it that way in the beginning, but then I started adding features like directory recursion and wanted to use the -r for that, and then added a function to simply count the files added each day and wanted to steal the -c for that, and so on... I'm sure you see the rabbit hole I've found myself in, which is what led me to trying to shove all the metadata options into suboptions of a single main option.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone was curious, my (probably) unnecessarily complex implementation is below.

In terms of behaviour, my list of options sits in a dict so I can add or remove items without modifying any of the argparse code or help strings. It builds the necessary strings for the help info and generates a list to compare against from the dict.

It then compares the input string against list of available options and build a new list to iterate through and executing functions as appropriate following certain rules.

-m assumes -me which becomes -mdtlsbrfcvae and is converted to a list.
Regardless of what else is given, if 'e' is in the string at all, set list to equal all metadata_choices.

-m with anything else gets parsed appropriately giving errors as necessary.

```
metadata_options={'d':'date',
                  't':'time',
                  'l':'length',
                  's':'size',
                  'b':'bitrate',
                  'r':'resolution',
                  'f':'framerate',
                  'c':'channels',
                  'v':'video codec',
                  'a':'aspect ratio',
                  'e':'everything'}

def metadata_option_extractor():
    metadata_choices=[]
    metadata_options_string=''
    punct=''
    last=len(metadata_options)
    count=0
    for choice,description in metadata_options.items():
        metadata_choices.append(choice)
        word=list(description)
        word.insert(0, '(')
        word.insert(2, ')')
        description = "".join(word)
        count += 1
        if count < last:
            punct=','
        else:
            punct='.'
        metadata_options_string += description + punct + ' '
    return metadata_choices,metadata_options_string

metadata_choices,metadata_options_string=metadata_option_extractor()

def msplit(mlist):
    new_mlist=[]
    for ch in mlist:
        if ch not in metadata_choices:
            raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(f"invalid choice: '{ch}' in '{mlist}' (choose from "+str(metadata_choices)+")")

        else:
            new_mlist.append(ch)

    if 'e' in new_mlist:
        new_mlist = metadata_choices

    return new_mlist

def get_arguments():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=DESCRIPTION)
    parser.add_argument('-g', action='store', default='d', nargs=1, choices=['d', 'l', 't', 'b'], help='Group by various criteria. (d)ate, (t)ime, (l)ength, (b)itrate. Default: Date')
    parser.add_argument('-m', type=msplit, nargs='?', const='e', help='Display metadata for each file. When given without any options it is taken to mean all options. Choices: '+metadata_options_string)
    parser.add_argument('-n', nargs='*', action='store', help='Go back only n many groups (typically days). A second argument may be added to limit the number of grouped results.', type=int)
    parser.add_argument('-r', action='store_true', help='Recurse subdirectories.')
    parser.add_argument('-s', action='store', help='Search for "Word(s)", separated by commas, in filenames.', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('-a', action='store_true', help='Switch search method from OR to AND. Requires -s')
    parser.add_argument('-x', action='store_true', help='Export filenames in quotes as a single line for use with another program.')
    parser.add_argument('-c', action='store_true', help='Count number of videos by group rather than list the videos.')

    parser.add_argument('files', nargs='*')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # Default behaviour
    if len(args.files) == 0:
        args.files="."

    return args
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call each `parser.add_argument` in a loop and it will work just fine.

Something like this will work:

```
METADATA_FIELDS = {
    'b': 'bitrate',
    # ... put the rest here
}

# Some other code, probably

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    # ... blah
)

for flag, name in METADATA_FIELDS.items():
    parser.add_argument(
        '-' + flag, '--' + name,
        dest='fields',
        action='append_const',
        const=name,
        help="Show {}".format(name)
    )

parser.add_argument(
    '-e', '--everything',
    dest='fields',
    action='store_const',
    const=list(METADATA_FIELDS.values())
)

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Doing this allows you to cut out the -m and have long names for each field as well. You will be able to combine short flags as well and order will be retained.

Comment: That's slick. I can still use it here, but in this case I actually want to keep -m to specify metadata and reduce the amount of typing input (I personally dislike long names), while leaving those same letters available to modify program behaviour rather than using them up just for metadata display.